# User ninjas answer from comment

Tags: support, accepted-answer

Sorry if this is a duplicate, but after searching I couldnt find a similar question.

Today a question was posted with some code that had weird behaviour. In the comments section of his question me and another guy started asking questions as debug info. E.g. "what happens when you do X". When we realised what the problem was (one of our questions lead to the root cause) the questioner responded his issue was fixed.

Now the tricky part was that just after we commented the question that lead to the solution, a different user 'ninjad' the answer and posted this as actual answer. Then the questioner marked this answer as correct answer, even though that user did not participate at all in the debugging process.

I suspect the user wanted to farm some reputation, as his reputation was quite low. Is this not allowed and if it aint, what should I do when such a thing would happen?

Thank you for your understanding and I am looking forward to your responses.

Comment: What you should do, is write a better answer than the kill-stealer.

Comment: It is not only allowed, but providing an answer beyond the comments is *encouraged*. "Stealing" it, though, is not so nice. Still: it may not be with bad intentions. I'd keep half an eye out for that user and see if he has a habit of doing this.